# Is a stable function guaranteed to produce the same result in a query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Let's say I run the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl) tbl1,
   (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM tbl) tbl2
```

Is the count guaranteed to be the same in the following function (let's say on a table that averages 1M inserts per minute, and the above query takes 10s to complete). I know if the function is`IMMUTABLE` it will return the same, and if it is`VOLATILE` it will (most likely) not return the same, but I'm curious how a `STABLE` function would work: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/xfunc-volatility.html.

Comment: postgres doesn't guarantee that stable or immutable function will always give the same answer, but you can make a CTE select all rows from from tbl and use tat for your count to get always the same answer.

Comment: Both table expressions will be computed separately.

Comment: @TheImpaler: but they are guaranteed to return the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A query (statement) sees a consistent view of the database as it was at the point in time when the execution started - regardless of how many sub-queries or derived tables it contains.

Any concurrent modification to the table is not visible to the running query.

So yes, it is guaranteed that bot sub-queries will return the same count.

This has nothing to do with "volatile" or "stable" functions. Those attributes are typically only important for the optimizer to take shortcuts. E.g.: the database free to cache function results per value for functions declared as immutable or stable for the duration of the query. But this is independent of the content that the query (and the functions) see.

---

Btw (unrelated to your question): it is a myth that `count(1)` is faster than `count(*)`. There is no database where this is true. In Postgres `count(1)` is even slightly *slower*.

Comment: I see, thanks for this. How does the database guarantee guarantee that no modifications can occur outside of the execution of the statement within the database?

Comment: It doesn't guarantee that no modification happens. It guarantees that the modification isn't visible.  https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/mvcc.html